# Orienting instances based on topology "flow" in geometry nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes

A common way to rotate instances is using 2 vectors, usually a normal vector and a tangent if you are working with curves. For meshes you'd use the normal vector to rotate against the surface and another vector parallel to the face that could be called the orient vector (or up vector).

So I'm trying to create an orient vector from 2 points per face but I don't have much control over it, so it mostly work but sometime it doesn't. I think what's going on is that it mostly pick 2 points (per quad) that are connected by an edge (doesn't matter which edge since I'm rotating squares) but sometimes it pick 2 points that are effectively giving a diagonal vector, which rotate the instance 45 degrees more or less and mess up the orientation for that particular instance.

Is there a fix for this?

[image]

[image]

Comment: According to your description and the picture, unfortunately, one can not draw any clear conclusions. `Edge Vertices` is based on the attribute domain *Edges*, but the instantiation is done at points. How are your *Geometry Nodes* built exactly? Please show us the whole node tree or even better: share your blend file with us https://blend-exchange.com/. Thank you!